# MongoDB: cannot use a cursor to iterate through all the data

Tags: java, mongodb, database-cursor

Update on update:

**Solved**! See this:
[MongoDB: cannot iterate through all data with cursor (because data is corrupted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649978/mongodb-cannot-iterate-through-all-data-with-cursor)

It's caused by corrupted data set. Not MongoDB or the driver.

---

I'm using the latest Java driver(2.11.3) of MongoDB(2.4.6). I've got a collection with ~250M records and I want to use a cursor to iterate through all of them. However, after 10 minutes or so I got either a false cursor.hasNext(), or an exception saying that the cursor does not exist on server.

After that I learned about cursor timeout and wrapped my cursor.next() with try/catch. If any exception, or hasNext() returned false before iterating through all the records, the program closes the cursor and allocates a new one, and then skip right back into context.

But later on I read about cursor.skip() performance issues... And the program just reached ~20M records, and cursor.next() after cursor.skip() throwed out "java.util.NoSuchElementException". I believe that's because the skip operation has timed out, which invalidated the cursor.

Yes I've read about skip() performance issues and cursor timeout issues... But now I think I'm in a dilemma where fixing one will break the other.

So, is there a way to gracefully iterate through all the data in a huge dataset?

@mnemosyn has already pointed out that I have to rely on range-based queries. But the problem is that I want to split all the data into 16 parts and process them on different machines, and the data is not uniformly distributed within any monotonic key space. If load balancing is desired, there must be a way to calculate how many keys are in a particular range and balance them. My goal is to partition them into 16 parts, so I have to find the quartiles of quartiles (sorry, I don't know if there's a mathematical term for this) of the keys and use them to split data.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I do have some ideas when the first seek is achieved by obtaining the partition boundary keys. If the new cursor times out again, I can simply record the latest tweetID and jump back in with the new range. However, the range query should be fast enough or otherwise I still get timeouts. I'm not confident about this...

Update:

Problem solved! I didn't realise that I don't have to partition data in a chunky way. A round-robin job dispatcher will do. See comments in the accepted answer.

Comment: why are you getting such large batches when it takes a long time to process 100 records?  You can make a batch 1 document and then as long as you can manage to process it in less than 10 minutes you can then get the next batch/document.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/

Comment: I didn't touch the cursor.batchSize(). I just encapsulate 100 records and push it to pipelines. I say 'pipelines' because there are 12 of them and the parallelisation makes things faster. It's not that I didn't touch the cursor for 10 minutes. But rather I kept pulling and pulling, and still end up getting a timeout.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649978/mongodb-cannot-iterate-through-all-data-with-cursor If making the pipelines faster would help, the problem in the link would never exist IMHO.

Comment: not true.  the issue is the work you are doing with the results, no how fast fetching the results takes.

Comment: So this was the same problem as the other question?  Same corrupt dataset?

Comment: Yes... The skip won't crash now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes. If you have a monotonic field, ideally an indexed field, you can simply walk along that. For instance, if you're using fields of type `ObjectId` as primary key or if you have a `CreatedDate` or something, you can simply use an `$lt` query, take a fixed number of elements, then query again using `$lt` of the smallest `_id` or `CreatedDate` you encountered in the previous batch.

Be careful about strict monotonic behavior vs. non-strict monotonic behavior: You might have to use `$lte` if the keys aren't strict, then prevent doing things twice on the dupes. Since the `_id` field is unique, `ObjectIds` are always strictly monotonic.

If you don't have such a key, things are a little more tricky. You can still iterate 'along the index' (whatever index, be it a name, a hash, a UUID, Guid, etc.). That works just as well, but it's hard to do snapshotting, because you never know whether the result you have just found was inserted before you started to traverse, or not. Also, when documents are inserted at the beginning of the traversal, those will be missed.

Comment: The records are tweets with unique tweetID as _id. Monoticity guaranteed. The problem is I don't know how to control range for a batch. For now, after getting 100 records, I put them in a list and push it to a processing pipeline. Since the pipeline runs very slow, I have to start pipeline instances on 16 machines and assign different FROM-TO ranges to them. All I know now is the total number of records. But the records are not evenly distributed in tweetID or any other keys.  So simply dividing the workload by ID would not not give good load balancing... Any suggestions on this? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's not pretty. I think you'll need a two-staged approach: The first stage scans through the collection by the thousands (big steps, doesn't return the entire data, just the ids, must be a covered query). It can start queuing up work immediately (to the secondary stage workers on many machines), e.g. in a round-robin manner. It continues to iterate so it has assigned a couple of million jobs to the second stage. It will probably only need a few minutes for that. You could store the number of documents `$lt` a given id since that never changes. Monotonicity is so nice :)

Comment: I got you. Currently I'm using one cursor on each of the pipeline machines. As you suggested I can use a primary machine for fetching from/writing to MongoDB, and job dispatching. This one will solve the load balancing problem. Thanks a lot!