# MongoDB: cannot iterate through all data with cursor (because data is corrupted)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Update:
The story is **off-topic** and the title **misleading**. The problem is caused by corrupted data set, not cursors, or MongoDB itself. But I would rather like to leave this thread here than to delete it, for that it might help other desperate people.

=== Original story starts here ===

It all starts here: [MongoDB: cannot use a cursor to iterate through all the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630795/mongodb-cannot-use-a-cursor-to-iterate-through-all-the-data)

I was trying to iterate through a cursor in Java, and it fails because my collection has too many records(~250M). I tried to allocate a new cursor and use cursor.skip to jump back in when the cursor gets timed out but cursor.skip itself times out.

@mnemosyn pointed out the right way for me: break the job into two stages: In the first stage, use a projected cursor to pull only the monotonic _id's of the records. Record the _id's, and then store it somewhere else as "checkpoints". During the second stage, I can then access any chunk of records as a checkpoint recorded.

So I wrote a javascript like this:

```
db=connect("localhost/twitter");

db.jobScheduler.drop();

for(var i = 0;i<16;++i)
{
    db.jobScheduler.save({_id:"s"+i,jobs:[]});
}

var c = db.tweets.find({},{_id:1}).sort({_id:1});

var totalCount = c.count();

var currentBatchSize = 0;
var currentNum = 0;

var currentShard = 0;
var startTid = 0;
var endTid = 0;
var currentTid = 0;

while(true)
{
    while(c.hasNext())
    {
        var doc = c.next()
        currentTid = doc._id;
        if(currentBatchSize == 0)
        {
            startTid = doc._id;
        }
        ++currentNum;
        ++currentBatchSize;
        if(currentBatchSize == 50000)
        {
            currentBatchSize = 0;
            endTid = doc._id;
            db.jobScheduler.update(
                {_id:"s"+currentShard},
                {$push:{jobs:[startTid,endTid]}});
            currentShard = (currentShard+1)%16;
            print(currentNum+"/"+totalCount+"("+currentNum*100/totalCount+"%)");
            print("["+startTid+","+endTid+"]");
        }
    }
    if(currentNum != totalCount){
        var c = db.tweets.find({_id:{$gt:currentTid}},{_id:1}).sort({_id:1});
        print("Cursor resetted....");
    }else
        break;
}
if(currentBatchSize != 0)
{
    currentBatchSize = 0;
    endTid = doc._id;
    db.jobScheduler.update(
        {_id:"s"+currentShard},
        {$push:{jobs:[startTid,endTid]}});
    currentShard = (currentShard+1)%16;
}
```

Considering that simply pulling _id only would still result in timeout, I added a guard like this:

```
if(currentNum != totalCount){
    var c = db.tweets.find({_id:{$gt:currentTid}},{_id:1}).sort({_id:1});
    print("Cursor resetted....");
}else
    break;
```

because when the cursor times out, I don't get an exception but a false cursor.hasNext().
Since I already recorded currentTid when iterating through them, using the range query `var c = db.tweets.find({_id:{$gt:currentTid}},{_id:1}).sort({_id:1});` will put me back in position, theoretically. However the poor little program end up like this:

```
[337242463750201340,345999466677010400]
21800000/253531208(8.598546968624076%)
[345999469818544100,346244305876295700]
Cursor resetted....
Cursor resetted....
Cursor resetted....
```

It seems to be stuck at the first occurrence of cursor timeout, forever. And the range query is not bringing me back.

Now I'm really confused. Iteration doesn't work. cursor.skip() doesn't work. Range query doesn't work. And what really works with MongoDB? Or is there something I'm doing really wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Update:

I had some discussion with @AsyaKamsky, he helped me to discover the following things:

1. setting cursor.batchSize() to 10 doesn't work.
2. The behaviour is not caused by an idle cursor waiting for 10 minutes. The cursor is pulling data rapidly from server, but still gets invalidated.
3. The real problem is that after it gets invalid in this way, I could never reallocate any usable cursors anymore. All the new cursors refuse to give me data. There is one possible workaround: close the cursor before this happens, and re-allocate one and use range query to jump back.

Experiments ongoing. Updating this thread in real-time :-)

Update: Failed! I tried renewing cursor after reading 50k records every time. It also gets trapped at this magical index 21800000! That's very close to my cursor.skip() failure offset!

Update:

Confirmed the guessing:

```
c = db.tweets.find().skip(21800000); //works
c = db.tweets.find().skip(21850000); //doesn't work
```

I'll try binary search on this range to find the magic number.

Update:

Ok... Magic number found.

db.tweets.find().itcount()
->21837006

db.tweets.find().count()
->253531208

Now what? This is really bad.

Comment: are you sure it's not just done?  you are looking for equality of totalCount (as it was when you started) and currentNum so if even a single document was inserted since you started, currentNum will blow right past totalNum without triggering the break and now you're forever querying for data that returns empty set.   Maybe change your condition to ">" from "!="  oh and see my note on the other question - I don't see why you need to do this - you should be manipulating the batchSize instead to make sure the cursor doesn't time out while you're working on a single batch.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Please note the output: 21800000/253531208(8.598546968624076%). This indicates that I still have a lot of them to process. Nobody else touches the database. (It's setup not for production by purely for my experiments) Also, consider 21800000 > 253531208, or 21800000 != 253531208. :-)

Comment: @AsyaKamsky could you please shed some lights into 'batchSize'? How will it affect cursor timeout? I mean in the script what I'm doing is perhaps the fastest thing I can achieve (only return _id), and it still times out. What value should be set as a batch size?

Comment: Yeah, I just took a look at the rest of your code - your writes to jobschedule collection are going to get slower and slower (you are pushing things to an ever growing array - do you plan to push 5000 batches to your 16 documents?  that's going to make those inserts get slower and slower.  May I recommend a different schema?

Comment: timeout is because before you go to next "batch" on the server (that's 100 times through your loop) it's over 10 minutes.  When you say find() you get back cursor and you get documents one at a time from it, but driver is fetching things from the server 100 at a time.  So if you take more than 10 minutes to process 100 returned documents you hit a timeout.  The issue is how long your loop is taking and as you push things to an array it'll take longer and longer.  Try inserting new documents instead of pushing new values to an array and I bet you'll avoid the timeout as it'll stay constant.

Comment: btw, you can confirm what I'm saying by looking in your mongod logs - the updates to jobscheduler will start out fast and get slower (they start getting logged once they pass 100ms) - since 100 updates are taking > 10 minutes, I'm guessing they are up past 5 seconds each!

Comment: @AsyaKamsky No I'm not pushing the batches to the documents. I'm just pushing the boundaries of them. I mean I don't push every tweetID into it, just a tuple [startID, endID]. The plan was to build these lists and let the cluster access this collection, so that they can use their own cursor to process the range [startID, endID). I've got 250M records. They should be split into 16 workers. Each batch should have 50K records to process, which yields the length of each db.jobScheduler.sN array: it should be 250M / 50K / 16 = 312. If pushing to arrays like this would get slow....

Comment: you push something new to an array every 50K documents and you only have 16 documents/arrays you are updating.  Ergo you are making 5000 updates/pushes to 16 arrays.  That's still over 300 updates and each one pushes a range (low and high boundry).

Comment: try replacing update(...) with insert({queue:"s"+N, boundries:[start,end]}) and see if it gets a lot faster...

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes you're right! Even with the parallel pipelines, the heavyweight GATE nlp parser still runs slowly. But not as slow as that. I can process 5 packages per seconds(each containing 100 tweets), which is 500 per second. I'm not sure if it's the default batchSize being too big so that I cannot actually touch the db in 10 minutes. I'll do some experiments with that.

Comment: try batch size of 10 (I suggested 1 in the other thread as an extreme but that will slow things down as it means that each document is a separate network round trip).

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I'll try to break them up now. Wait a minute. :-)

Comment: oh, almost forgot, you can also raise the cursor timeout value, 10min is just the default. <- never mind, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8188 shows you cannot raise it, just disable it. I should probably summarize this into an answer, huh?

Comment: No it doesn't speed things up. One update vs 50k cursor.next() and it gets insignificant.

Comment: Also I think my problem is a bit different from the usual cursor timeout... I'm pulling all the time. I can see network traffic within the cluster. So that should not be a socket timeout (as the pointer you gave suggested - oh, that's still a very useful link! thanks!)

Comment: @AsyaKamsky The cursor gets lost again in the exactly same position:21800000/253531208(8.598546968624076%)
[345999469818544100,346244305876295700]                                                                                   Cursor resetted.... I already broke the ranges into different records. I will try tweaking the batchSize now.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Also, please note the problem: after the timeout, I can never get back again. I cannot allocate a new cursor and jump back in. I get constant "cursor resetted" which indicates that none of the shiny new cursors have true cursor.hasNext()

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Setting batchSize to 10 doesn't work either.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Please see my updated question. I've got a bad feeling...

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I actually tested that. The variable scope in mongo shell is pretty interesting: `var x = 1; {var x = 2;} print(x);` and you will get 2.

Comment: ok, you should probably reIndex() the collection - it's possible that the _id index is corrupt.  reIndex() will take a while but it will drop and recreate the _id index.  The alternative is to compact the collection or repair the database. (I didn't see all your comments when I commented before)

Comment: btw, have you checked the logs? I would expect some stack traces there if your index or data is corrupt on disk.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky The tweets collection is a result collection of a map-reduce operation from the raw data. Within these hours I've already reconstructed the tweets collection. I'm testing with cursor.itcount() again. Will report back after some sleep(time for +8 people to sleep now :-). I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Confirmed. It's corrupted data, not myth about cursors... After rebuilding the collection it seems to be fine now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a story of unusual data corruption, and not about the title or most of the body of the "question"

Comment: Yeah, already updated the question. Thanks for the reminder, but I'd still love to keep this thread, just in case that someone else falls into this pit again. (It's quite unobvious isn't it?)

Comment: it wasn't obvious because it's quite rare, I think.